# Mac internal trackpad and keyboard not working on Yosemite

Tags: mac, macbook-pro

I have found some threads describing this problem on Google, but none of them provided an (working) answer.

I have **installed beta of Yosemite** on my MBA (2013). I made no back-ups, but it's my secondary computer and I have no important data here. The problem is: internal trackpad and keyboard stopped working suddenly - during internet browsing on Safari. What's more, mac was running pretty slow during the first hours after the problem occured. Then, this issue fixed itself.

When I connect mouse and keyboard via USB - it' all OK.
What I already did:

-PRAM Reset

-SMC Reset

-checked all what I could in system settings UI

-Reinstalling OS X

-Hard reset (erased disc) to factory settings with Maverics OS.

However, it should not be a hardware problem - I can enter recovery mode ( Cmd + R ) with my internal keyboard.

Does someone has any more suggestions ?